# Removing images from screen in android

Tags: java, android, image

I am making an android game that should delete some falling images from the screen once they are tapped.
I thought that I maybe could use some similar code as seen on the `doDraw()` method, that deletes them once they hit the bottom of the screen, that also plays a sound, and checks the players health value. But I need a little bit of help with this. If anyone could post me any code and explain to me how this is done I would be very grateful!

This is the code that I am using so far:

```
public class ExampleView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
class ExampleThread extends Thread
{
    private ArrayList<Parachuter> parachuters;
    private Bitmap parachuter;
    private Paint black;

    private boolean running;

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Context mContext;
    private Context mContext1;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Handler mHandler1;
    private GameScreenActivity mActivity;

    private long frameRate;
    private boolean loading;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public MediaPlayer mp1;
    public int parachuterIndexToResetAndDelete;
    public int canvasGetWidth;
    public int livesLeftValue;

    public ExampleThread(SurfaceHolder sHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
    {
        mSurfaceHolder = sHolder;
        mHandler = handler;
        mHandler1 = handler;
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = (GameScreenActivity) context;

        parachuters = new ArrayList<Parachuter>();
        parachuter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.parachuteman);
        black = new Paint();
        black.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        black.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        running = true;

        // This equates to 26 frames per second.
        frameRate = (long) (1000 / 26);
        loading = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            Canvas c = null;
            try
            {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    doDraw(c);
                    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                    if (diff < frameRate)
                        Thread.sleep(frameRate - diff);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), black);
        canvasGetWidth = canvas.getWidth();

        //Draw
        for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(parachuter, parachuters.get(i).getX(), parachuters.get(i).getY(), null);
            parachuters.get(i).tick();
        }

        //Remove
        for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
        {
        if (parachuters.get(i).getY() > canvas.getHeight()) {
            parachuters.remove(i);
            onPlaySound();
            checkLivesLeftValue();
        }
    }
    }


    private void checkLivesLeftValue() {
        Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "lives = " + livesLeftValue);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (livesLeftValue == 3) {
            //Message to display: "You lost!
            Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "calling onMethod now");
            onMethod();
        }
        else {
            livesLeftValue = livesLeftValue + 1;
            Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "increased lives to " + livesLeftValue);
        }
    }
    public void onMethod() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You lost!", 15).show();
                livesLeftValue = 0;
                //Tell the user that he lost:
                android.content.Context ctx = mContext;
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, playerLostMessageActivity.class);  
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ctx.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    } 

    public void onPlaySound()
    {
        try {
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.bombsound);
        mp1.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mp1.release();
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return false;
        float x1 = event.getX();
        float y1 = event.getY();

        initiateDrawParachuters();

        return true;
    }

    public void initiateDrawParachuters()
    {
        drawParachuter1();
    }

    private void drawParachuter1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 1
        x = 10;
        y = 40;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter2();
    }

    private void drawParachuter2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 2
        x = 50;
        y = 80;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter3();
    }

    private void drawParachuter3() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 90;
        y = 120;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter4();
    }

    private void drawParachuter4() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 4
        x = 140;
        y = 150;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter5();
    }

    private void drawParachuter5() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 5
        x = 190;
        y = 170;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter6();
    }

    private void drawParachuter6() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 6
        x = 240;
        y = 180;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
        drawParachuter7();
    }

    private void drawParachuter7() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter nr. 6
        x = 290;
        y = 180;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);
    }

    public void drawParachuters()
    {
            Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
            parachuters.add(p);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x=" + x + " y=" + y, 15).show();
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean bRun)
    {
        running = bRun;
    }

    public boolean getRunning()
    {
        return running;
    }
}

/** Handle to the application context, used to e.g. fetch Drawables. */
private Context mContext;

/** Pointer to the text view to display "Paused.." etc. */
private TextView mStatusText;

/** The thread that actually draws the animation */
private ExampleThread eThread;

public ExampleView(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
    eThread = new ExampleThread(holder, context, new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m)
        {
           // mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
           // mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
        }
    });

    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    return eThread.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public ExampleThread getThread()
{
    return eThread;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if (eThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED)
    {
        eThread = new ExampleThread(getHolder(), getContext(), getHandler());
        eThread.start();
    }
    else
    {
        eThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    boolean retry = true;
    eThread.setRunning(false);

    while (retry)
    {
        try
        {
            eThread.join();
            retry = false;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Parachuter class touched boolean:

```
    public boolean isTouched() {
    return touched;
}

public void setTouched(boolean touched) {
    this.touched = touched;
}
```

Comment: Instead of chaining a bunch of methods together for creating your parachuters, you may instead want to try being more straight foward by creating and adding them all at once.

`parachuters.add(new Parachuter(50, 80)); parachuters.add(new Parachuter(90, 120));`

etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a parachuter is touched you just need to set a boolean in the Parachuter class signifying that it is now dead and should be removed. You can then change your onDraw remove section to look like this.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
    {
    if (parachuters.get(i).getY() > canvas.getHeight()) {
        parachuters.remove(i);
        onPlaySound();
        checkLivesLeftValue();
    } else if(parachuters.get(i).isDead) {
        parachuters.remove(i);
    }
```

Comment: What would i then add to my activity(the one above) except from your code? Take a look at what i added to my parachuter class above

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking. Are you asking what your Parachuter class should look like? If so your two methods look like they are fine additions to the Parachuter class.

Comment: Thx, but i Wonder what the other class should look like. I've added your code to the doDraw() method, but do i need anything Else??? In that case, what???

Comment: Really not sure what you are asking, sorry. Maybe now that you have updated code you could try asking a new question specific to your new issue?